# Is it possible to use Selenium / PHPUnit outside the browser?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, phpunit

Right now this is my workflow to write tests for a website:

1. Record using Selenium IDE plugin in Firefox
2. Export Test Case As >> PHP (PHP Unit)
3. Run the tests on a Windows machine that has PHPUnit installed as well as the Selenium extension for it using this command:

`phpunit --verbose --log-junit some\path\result.xml some\path\test.php`

What this command does is runs the test and saves the output (assertions and failures) in a log file called result.xml. And all has been good.

But now I have run into a need to test a part of the site that involves flash and I am using an application called Arthropod to capture the requests and responses coming to and from the flash component on the site.

**Is there any way I can get selenium to to capture the text that appears on this program's interface?**

Comment: You want Selenium to run on Arthropod??

Comment: @Maitreya I guess, I mean like how one can use selenium to grab the contents of a div from a webpage I want to grab the contents of the Arthropod UI. As in the text that shows up on it.

Comment: @Maitreya there's even a save button on Arthropod, if I could get Selenium or some other tool to click that button and press enter on the dialog that shows up that would be good enough. This button saves the contents of the Arthropod screen to a html log file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Arthropod is an AIR application. If it is associated with the browser you may try using seleniumForAir for your testing.

You may like to have a look [here](http://corlan.org/2008/08/15/functional-testing-framework-for-air-ajax-apps-based-on-selenium/).

Comment: I ended up accomplishing this via AutoIt. It reminds me of a selenium IDE but for desktop, browser anything.